# JS Array output Trouble

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I have an array of "active classes" as each class becomes active it gets added to my array. I would like to take that array test to make sure each class is only in it ONCE and then append its text to the dom as a li.

```
var filtersArray = [],
activeFilters = state.activeFilter.replace('.', ' ');
//by default .mix and none is in activeFilters
//.hatch,.sedan,.suv get added later -> these are the only ones I want
// activeFilters really equals -> activeFilters = ['.mix','.hatch','.sedan','.suv'];

if (activeFilters != ".mix" || activeFilters != "none") {
if ($.inArray(activeFilters, filtersArray) == -1) {
    filtersArray.push(activeFilters);
    for (index = 0; index < filtersArray.length; ++index) {
        //console.log(filtersArray[index]);
        $('.filter-result-list').append('<li>' + filtersArray + '<i class="close">x</i></li>');
    }

}
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/im_cr/8zyhhftL/11/

Comment: state variable is undefined. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: @krg I am using the mixItup filter plugin that state.activeFilter returns an array. that array by default starts with '.mix' and as classes become active it gets added to state.activeFilter.